# Change Color of Bars in Facetted Bar Plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to change some colours in the following plot:

The code below gave me the following plot, already quite pretty:

[image]

I still would like to change the colors of the 4 bars in my plots, to let's say "green4", "darkgreen", "orangered3" and "red3", but not change anything else to my plot (like used labels from the legend (of course the colors should change as well in the legend)). My data (df) has three variables. Variable 'V1n' is just a numeric version of the factor variable V1. It's just the last bit i can't get my head around, does anyone know how to change the four colors used by default?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
glimpse(df)

# Observations: 300
# Variables: 3
# $ METING.f <fctr> Meting 0, Meting 0, Meting 0, Meting 0, Meting 0,...
# $ V1n      <int> 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1,...
# $ V1       <fctr> Ja, meerdere, namelijk..., Ja, Ja, meerdere, name...  


ggplot(df, aes(x = V1n, fill = V1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])), 
                stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  facet_grid(.~ METING.f) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Beschikt uw instelling over een\naandachtsfunctionaris kindermishandeling?\n") +
  labs(title = " ",
       x = "Vraag 1",
       y = "Percentage")  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Try adding: `scale_fill_manual(values = c("green4", "darkgreen", "orangered3", "red3"), name = "Beschikt..." )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set wanted fill/colors using [**`scale_fill_manual`**](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html).

```
scale_fill_manual(name = "Beschikt...",
                  values = c("green4", "darkgreen", "orangered3", "red3"))
```

Or you can use one of the [brewer pallets](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html) with `scale_fill_brewer`.

PS.: If you don't want to set name of fill in `scale_fill_manual` you can set it in `labs()` (as you did for `title` and `x`). For example `labs(fill = "yourFillName")`.